# C# Create Excel workbook with 1 sheet by default

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I'm trying to create an Excel file with C# COM interop but seems it create it by default with 3 sheets instead of empty or only one. 
What is needed to create it Empty or just with one:

```
Excel.Application xl = null;
Excel._Workbook wb = null;

// Create a new instance of Excel from scratch
xl = new Excel.Application();
xl.Visible = true;     
wb = (Excel._Workbook)(xl.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value));

wb.SaveAs(@"C:\a.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,
 null, null, false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared,
 false, false, null, null, null);
```

Comment: I think this is the default behavior in Excel. If you open excel and create a new document, it has three sheets. Maybe you just need to delete sheets two and three.

Comment: Or you can try your hand on a simple but handly library NPOI http://code.google.com/p/npoi/ that gives you alot of flexibility especially for basic to intermediate excel features. If your output only needs to be opened from Office 2010 or later, you can also consider OpenXML. COM Interop is likely to give you alot of problem in unattended, non-interactive client applications. See this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Take a look at MSDN's explanation of [Workbooks.Add Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.add.aspx).

1. Try `Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet)`, or
2. See if you can set the `xl.SheetsInNewWorkbook` property to 0 or 1.

I went ahead and verified this. Here is the code:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application xl = null;
            _Workbook wb = null;

            // Option 1
            xl = new Application();
            xl.Visible = true;
            wb = (_Workbook)(xl.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet));

            // Option 2
            xl = new Application();
            xl.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1;
            xl.Visible = true;
            wb = (_Workbook)(xl.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I used the option 2: "xl.SheetsInNewWorkbook =1" and thats solve the problem.

Comment: @Moti, Glad to help. Seeing your new here, if the answer is correct, it's customary to accept the answer (check the check-mark). Additionally helpful answers can also be up voted (the up arrow). :)

Comment: Seems I can't answer on the question for at least 8 hours as I have "•Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 7 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead".

Answer (score 2):

```
Excel.Application xl = null;
Excel._Workbook wb = null;

xl = new Excel.Application();
xl.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1;
xl.Visible = true;

wb = (_Workbook)(xl.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value));
```