# Merge 3 worksheets into 1 Excel file (xlsx)

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I am parsing some data into a Excel sheet and I am generating 3 Excel sheets (Compliance1.xls, Compliance2.xls, Compliance3.xls) by using the below code:

```
    owb.SaveAs(Input_File+@"\Compliance1.xls",
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, 
Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false, false, 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange                    
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

I want one Excel file to be generated with 3 of compliance sheets in it.

Comment: Seems like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70143/merge-multiple-xslt-stylesheets

Comment: from where do you get data? dataset? or something else?

Comment: @likewhoa im talking about microsoft excel

Comment: @waqas im writing data to excel sheet by using  osheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)owb.ActiveSheet; and  osheet.Cells[RowCol + 3, 2] = "Data";

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Do you want to copy 3 sheets of work into a single sheet, or to create 3 sheets in a single workbook?

Comment: please see my provided answer... below. may be this is helpful

Comment: @DarrenYoung i want 1 workbook with 3 sheets

Answer (score 0):

here are some examples . please go through these.

[How to create excel file with multiple sheets from DataSet using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156616/how-to-create-excel-file-with-multiple-sheets-from-dataset-using-c-sharp)

[Trying to add multiple sheets to excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425746/trying-to-add-multiple-sheets-to-excel)

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/generate-excel-with-multiple-sheet-from-dataset1

Please do google before you post new question.

Comment: From the Help Center "Provide context for links

Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."